# How to Pass multiple Values in objType parmeter

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, object-type, recordtype

How to pass multiple values in objType field to a method parameter

Currently i'm storing single row in objType field and passing that as an input to an oracle sp, now i need to store and pass multiple rows in objType. How to achieve that? 
I've tried creating objType like multidimensional one: 
    Object[] objType = new Object[3][3], 
it doesn't help.
Please see my sample code below and help.

```
Object[] objType = new Object[3];
objType[0] = new Integer(lineNo);
objType[1] = new String(itemCode);
objType[2] = new Integer(ORDER_QTY));


structs[index]=conn.createStruct("XXHDB_REC", objType);
        Array reportsArray = ((OracleConnection)
```

conn).createOracleArray("XXHDB_TBL_TYPE", structs);

```
//Input to oracle package
oracleCallableStmt.setArray(4, reportsArray);
```

I need to store 'n' of rows with fixed 3 columns. [n][3].

```
Stored Proc Definition:
create_booking(p_reservation_id  => p_reservation_id, 
p_Hybris_Cust_nbr => p_Hybris_Cust_nbr,
p_cust_nbr        => p_cust_order_no,
p_group           => j.GROUP_ID,
p_order_lines     => v_rec) --> this is the input field
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the definition of your stored procedure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code `Object[] objType = new Object[3][3]` does not work as objType has the wrong type, it should be `Object[][] objType = new Object[n][3]`. However I strongly recommend to not use `Object` as type if you know the values you want to store, instead you could use some sort of container for them like:

```
class Container {
    private Integer lineNo;
    private String itemCode;
    private Integer ORDER_QTY;

    // rest omitted
}
```

And then use this as your type your array or whatever you want to use. `Container[] objType = new Container[n];`.

Comment: But i wanna pass Table type as input parameter, Can i pass with class object like this?

Comment: Yes, you can use a 2 dimensional array for that as you wanted with `Object[][] objType = new Object[n][3]` and add to it with `objType[index] = table` where `table` is a normal array like `Object[] table = new Object[3]`.

Comment: I've created a 2D array  Object[][] objType = new Object[itemSize][3];
                 Object[] obj = new Object[3];
After assigning values to obj, i've assigned it to objType, objType[index]=obj;                                      
After all, while assigning objType to structs, structs[index]=conn.createStruct("XXHDB_REC", objType);
i'm getting "Java.sql.sqlException: Inconsistent java and sql object types"